# Get a specific word from a specific line from a text file in Android

Tags: java, android

```
String line = "";
        int lineNo;
        try 
        {
            File file = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                //char[] inputBuffer1 = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
                for (lineNo = 1; lineNo < 20; lineNo++) 
                {
                     if (lineNo == 1)
                     {
                         line = br.readLine();
                         etFName.setText(line);


                     }else//{br.readLine();}   
                     if (lineNo == 2)
                     {
                             line = br.readLine();
                             char c = line.charAt(0);
                             //char c =line.charAt(0);
                             String s1 = Character.toString(c); 
                             //String Str1 = line;
                             //String bloodgroup = String.copyValueOf(Str1, 10,13);
                             fBldGp.setText(s1);
                     }else//{br.readLine();} 
                     if (lineNo == 5)
                     {
                         line = br.readLine();
                         char c = line.charAt(0);
                         String s1 = Character.toString(c);
                         etMName.setText(s1);                        
                     }else
                     if (lineNo == 6)
                     {
                         line = br.readLine();
                         char c = line.charAt(0);
                         String s1 = Character.toString(c);
                         mBldGp.setText(s1);                         
                     }else br.readLine();
                }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This gives me the required line but i am unable to get the specific word from that line 
and add it to the textview in android layout. Please help me.

My expected output is to display the word of the line 1,2,5,6th line leaving first 10 alphabets of every line.

Comment: So whats the problem here? What is the expected output and what is your current output?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you list of all words(including space):

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

You can access each word like this:

```
foreach(String word in words) {
     System.out.println(word.trim()); // trim gets rid of the space from the beginning & end
}
```

Comment: well i dont want to trim this instead i want to get the words of the desired line like 1,2,5,6 and after leaving first 10 word i want to get the remaining word of the line in to my textview or editText

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, if you want a specific word you already know or whatever word is in a specific index value. But you can always check something like:

```
if(line.contains("word"){
     fBldGp.setText("word");
}
```

But other than that then line.substring would give you a word starting at a specific index

Comment: but it gives error when i use it in my for loop....
                for (lineNo = 1; lineNo < 20; lineNo++) 
                {
                  if (lineNo == 1)
                     {
                   line = br.readLine();
                   //String text = line.substring(5, 15);
                   etFName.setText(line);
                         
                             
                     }else

Comment: im still not able to do so as my i have multiple line and and i use line.substring it shows error

Comment: Thank's to all of You for the help I have got the Answer